# Xamarin Android Memory Usage

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am thinking about Xamarin Android App, Actually I want to run my android app on my own/physical device which contains just one carousel page in it so, how much memory it will take this app in my mobile phone. Anyone?

I just want to know about the memory which it will take.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you could trace the memory usage for your Xamarin project. You may use Android Studio, please refer to [Inspect your app's memory usage with Memory Profiler](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/memory-profiler).

First, you just build your Xamarin app for **Debug** and deploy it to a physical device. Don't forget to disable Use Shared Runtime in the Android project build options.

After you deploy your app, use Memory Profile in Android Studio to trace the memory usage. You could follow these steps,

1.Click **View > Tool Windows > Profiler**

2.Select the device and app process you want to profile from the Android Profiler toolbar. In this step, you should find the Visual Studio debug process in **Other debuggable processes** and select it,

[image]

3.Click anywhere in the MEMORY timeline to open the Memory Profiler

Then you could trace your memory usage in Memory Profiler.

[image]

Hope it helps!